# view function not found in django

Tags: python, django, url, routes, match

When trying to click on a button to redirect to getonboard.html I get the following error:

`django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'getonboard' not found. 'getonboard' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

artdb/urls.py:

```
path('getonboard/',views.getonboard,name='getonboard'),
```

templates/artdb/base.html:

```
<p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="{% url 'getonboard' %}" role="button">Get onboard &raquo;</a></p>
```

artdb/views.py:

```
def getonboard(request):

    return render(request,'artdb/getonboard.html')
```

templates/artdb/getonboard.html:

```
{% extends "artdb/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h2>getonboard template</h2>
     <p>this is the getonboard text</p>
{% endblock content %}
```

full main urls.py:

```
"""winmalist URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('artdb/', include('artdb.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]+static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

full artdb/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from artdb.views import PersonList

from . import views

app_name='artdb'

urlpatterns = [
#    path('base/',views.base,name='base.html'),
    path('getonboard/',views.getonboard,name='getonboard'),
    path('index/',views.index,name='index'),
    path('persons/',PersonList.as_view()),
    path('',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='artdb/base.html')),
    path('test2',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='artdb/test2.html')),
#     path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
#     path('contract', views.contract, name='contract'), 
#     path('<int:person_id>/test1/', views.test1, name='test1'),
]
```

any thoughts?

Comment: is artdb.urls included from a main urls.py file? Do you have a line `app_name = artdb` in the artdb/urls.py file? I can only guess that your URLs might be namespaced. Show us the entire artdb/urls.py file and show us your main urls.py file.

Comment: added full urls.py

Comment: Your URLs are name-spaced, because you added `app_name = 'artdb'`. So all your url patters in the app `artdb` start with `artdb:`, e.g. `artdb:getonboard` and `artdb:index`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you include urlpatterns from a different app, you'll usually namespace those URLs by adding the line `app_name = 'artdb'` to the urls.py file inside the app. So, if the main urls.py file has the line:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('artdb/', include('artdb.urls')),
    ...]
```

And the artdb/urls.py file has these lines:

```
app_name = 'artdb'

urlpatterns = [
     path('getonboard/', views.getonboard, name='getonboard'),
     ...]
```

then you can reverse this URL by namespacing the name:

```
reverse('artdb:getonboard')
```

This allows you to use the same name in multiple apps (e.g. `index` would be common), having `artdb:index` and `user:index` for example.